# How to add horizontal lines between (single or multiple) figures?

Tags: pdftex, winedt, scientific-workplace

I don't understand how to insert these lines above and below the figure, also how to adjust the size of the figures?

[image: The Page]

Comment: I am new to this, what is TikZ?

Comment: There are packages like float which can add lines before and after each figure.   You can always insert you own lines and spaces (see \rule or \hrule and \vspace of \vskip. The width of a figure/table/float is \columnwidth (or \textwidth for figure*), and the height depends on the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your image is available in a graphic, the image size is adjustable using the `width=` option of `\includegraphics`...

Or if you have to add the table to the left, you can use `\scalerel*` to force the image height to match the size of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,scalerel}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
\hrulefill\vspace{15pt}\par
\setbox0=\hbox{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
Go\\\hline
Clear\\\hline
3dProject\\\hline
X-Rotate\\\hline
Y-Rotate\\\hline
Z-Rotate\\\hline
EraseRota\\\hline
Body-Tog\\\hline
RotAx-Tog\\\hline
Flash-Tog\\\hline
Persp-Tog\\\hline
NUMERICS\\\hline
UTILITIES\\\hline
Quit\\\hline
\end{tabular}}
\centerline{\copy0\scalerel*{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}{\copy0}}
\captionof{figure}{Here is my caption}
\medskip
\hrulefill\par
\vspace{15pt}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\captionof{figure}{Here is my other caption}
\medskip
\hrulefill
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Deleting my comment... Not really nice approach my approach because I would need more things for the vertical spacing (I mean if added a minipage inside tabular that would be a wrong approach). (+1)